# Trouble adding package to library() after installing package

Tags: r, rjava, xlconnect

I keep getting the same error, for both first for XLConnect, (which I thought was a java problem) and now rJava (which is also not working). This is the error message I get when I library(rJava):

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:  .onLoad failed
>   in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:   call: dyn.load(file,
>   DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)   error: unable to load shared object
>   '/Users/snyderk2/Library/R/3.4/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
>   dlopen(/Users/snyderk2/Library/R/3.4/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6):
>   Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Users/snyderk2/Library/R/3.4/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so   Reason:
>   image not found

I am new to R, and just need to figure out how to get these packages working, thanks!

Comment: Are you just trying to read Excel file in R? It would probably be easier to use a package like `readxl` that doesn't have a Java dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try (check your java version and change accordingly):

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = "C:/Program Files/Java/jre-9.0.1")
```

And then load library.

Install package `xlsx` if you are trying to access Excel file by entering `install.packages("xlsx", dependencies = T)` in your console.

Comment: I did the sys.setenv check, and then tried to load xlsx, but had the same error message. I was able to load openxlsx.

Comment: what's your java version

Comment: java recently got updated, it might have change your path for java

Answer (score 0):

Another R package for working with excel data which does not require rJava is openxlsx.  I've found it works faster than java-based packages, which is a nice bonus.